# The Raspberry Pi screen cannot show the real-time numerical value received by UART communication

Tags: python, uart

Send eight numerical values from Arduino to Raspberry Pi. On *serial1.py*, real-time numerical values appear well in the terminal. However, in the *UI.py*, the `print(serial_result)` value that comes out when the button is pressed is the old value, not the real time value. For example, if you increase the humidity, you will get a higher value after 20 seconds to 3 minutes. I want to see the correct real-time value even after pressing the button on *UI.py*. Attach the *serial1.py* and *UI.py* codes.

```py
import sys
import rain
import serial1
import dust_api
import dust
import rain_forecast

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow
import set_address

form_class = uic.loadUiType("main.window.ui")[0]
    
# 화면을 띄우는데 사용되는 Class 선언
class WindowClass(QMainWindow, form_class):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.fontSize = 10

        # 버튼에 기능을 연결하는 코드
        self.weather_button.clicked.connect(self.set_weather_dust)
        # self.weather_button_2.clicked.connect(self.set_weather_rain)
        # self.weather_button_3.clicked.connect(self.set_weather_th)
        # self.weather_button_4.clicked.connect(self.set_weather_CO)
        # self.address_button.clicked.connect(self.set_address)

def set_weather_dust(self):
    serial_result = serial1.serial_check()
    result = dust_api.dust_check()
    print(serial_result)

    dust_in = dust.dust_check_in(float(serial_result[4]))
    self.textEdit.setText(
        "실내 온도           :     " + (serial_result[0]) + " ºC \n" + "실내 습도           :     " + serial_result[
            1] + "  % \n" + "실내 미세먼지     :    " + dust_in)
    self.textEdit_2.setText("지금 실외 미세먼지 센서 수치는?     " + (serial_result[5]) +
                            " ㎍/㎥  " + "<" + dust.dust_check_out(float(serial_result[5]))
                            + ">" + "\n선택한 지역의 미세먼지 API 수치는?   \n" +
                            "(" + result["sidoName"] + " " + result["stationName"] + ")   " +
                            "pm10수치 :  " + result["pm10수치"] + " ㎍/㎥" + "  <" +
                            result["10형태"] + ">  " + "pm2.5수치 :  " + result["pm2.5수치"]
                            + " ㎍/㎥ " + "  <" + result["2.5형태"] + ">")
    self.textEdit_3.setText("지금 실내 미세먼지 센서 수치는?     " + (serial_result[4]) + " ㎍/㎥  " + "< " + dust_in + ">")
```

*serial1.py*

```py
from collections import defaultdict
import serial

ser = serial.Serial('COM9', 9600)
def serial_check():
    while True:
        try:
            f = str(ser.readline().decode("utf-8").strip())
        except:
            continue
        data_list = f.split(',')
        # print(f)
        keys = []
        values = []
        # print(data_list)

        if len(data_list) == 8:
            for data in data_list:
                values.append(str(data))
            # del ser
            # print(values)
            return values
        else:
            continue
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    serial_check()
```

Comment: The second code is serial.py or serial1.py?

Comment: It's serial1.py